# How do I write the follow rule in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to figure out how should I write my firestore rule such that `Only the matching uid in the key of the document's key-value pair` can have permission to write.

More specifically:

my firestore structure is something like:

```
'Items LA' -> 'Pasadena' -> {'awjij53dHh3dnYAh': {itemInformation}}
collection -> document -> fields
```

where `'awjij53dHh3dnYAh'` is the seller ID.

***and I want to write a rule such that it gives `awjij53dHh3dnYAh` permission to write in that field.***

Currently what I have is the following:

```
  match /Items%20LA/{cityName}/{data}{
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == data.key; // This is where I am not sure how to write what I want to accomplish
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `data.key` meant to be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing - the match path for a rule only includes the path components of a document (collections and document IDs), and not fields.  Also, it doesn't need any URL escaping.  Just match on "/Items LA/{cityName}".

Second, if you want to refer to the names of fields in a document in a rule expression, you should know that [`request.resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data) is a Map of all the incoming fields, and you will have to use its API to deal with the those key/value pairs.

Third, if you want to find out which fields of a document changed, you will need to compare the state of the document before and after the change using the [MapDiff](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) API.

Putting all this together, you will need to check that only the field changed that equals the user's UID:

```
match /Items LA/{cityName} {
    allow write: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly([request.auth.uid]);
}
```

Comment: when I took away the URL escaping %20 it gave me the error:  **Error saving rules - Line 5: Missing 'match' keyword before path.; Line 5: Unexpected 'LA'.; Line 5: mismatched input 'LA' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}; Line 5: Missing 'match' keyword before path.; Line 6: missing '}' at 'allow'; Line 62: Unexpected '}'.**

Comment: But other than that it worked like a charm! Thanks Doug! (I cant edit your answer but there's a missing if before the request.resource)

Answer (score 0):

What you want probably is

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == $(data)
//or this
allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.id
```